# Entity Framework and Mysql Transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

> How do i do EF 4.x for update lock with transaction? how do i do the
>   below MYSQL sql using EF?

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT  @A:=TagCount FROM TopicTag where Tag = 'SIMPLE' FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE TopicTag SET TagCount=@A+1 where Tag = 'SIMPLE';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a normalized DB to me. `TagCount` shouldn't be stored, it should be computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a transaction using a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object. [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has example usage.

Within the transaction, the core part of your code might look like:

```
var tag = context.TopicTags.Single(x => x.Tag == "SIMPLE");
tag.TagCount++;
```